# Identifying coordinate adjectives

Tags: adjectives

Most of the coordinate adjectives fall under the quality/opinion classification. However, we do have many adjective combinations as in the following examples:

Big, red apple (or Red, big apple)

Tall, elegant tower (or Elegant, tall tower)

Tiny, cozy cottage (or Cozy, tiny cottage)

If a coordinate adjective is decided by the rule of the same genre/classification of adjectives, it is confusing to decide whether these are coordinate adjectives or not -as they are from different genres. If by adding "and" between the adjectives, it is a little easier.

1. What should be the criteria to decide on coordinate adjectives?

2)Is the genre (as in opinion, size, age, shape, colour, origin, material) only applicable to
cumulative adjectives?

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151184/discussion-on-question-by-brp7-identifying-coordinate-adjectives); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.